# RelativeLayout is not Scrollable in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-scroll, android-relativelayout

Any idea why the following layout is not scrollable? I have a `RelativeLayout` in a `ScrollView`. The Views fit on the screen. however they are covered whenever the keyboard pops up. I want to make the screen scrollable when the keyboard pops up, because it covers the Login and password EditBoxes so it is har to see what someone is typing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.alarm.alarmmobile.android.view.RobotoLightTextView
            android:id="@+id/passcode_login_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/passcode_login_body"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passcode_login_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/passcode_login_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="@string/login_textview_username"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passcode_login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/passcode_login_username"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/login_textview_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <com.alarm.alarmmobile.android.view.RobotoLightButton
            android:id="@+id/passcode_login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/passcode_login_password"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/login_button_login" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Show us how it's look

Comment: Try putting `android:orientation="vertical"` in the ScrollView.

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" does not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="..." // your activity here
    ....
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan">
/>
```

**NOTE:** Not sure if adding `adjustPan` will cause the problem to come up again or not.

Comment: This works, but is there any alternative of achieving the same thing? I need to have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 1):

On the activity or fragment class of this layout you have to call this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: This works, but is there any alternative of achieving the same thing? I need to have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Answer (score 0):

If everything can fit on the screen, the `ScrollView` will not be able to scroll anywhere. If there is a component that is not fully visible then the scroll should be available to see the rest of the component. Without being able to see what the problem is it's hard to find the exact solution.

Comment: You are right the two EditBoxes fit on the screen. They are covered whenever the keyboard pops up. That is when I want to scroll the content. How do I do that?

Comment: How do I make it scrolable even though the everything fits on the screen?